# almacenar html en un textfield en django y renderizarlo en template como html

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Si yo almaceno un texto en textfield y el text contiene etiquetas html, por ejemplo  < b> informe 2020 < /b > ,
al momento de hacer el render de la template pues obviamente ese texto
se mostrata < b>informe  2020< /b>
mi pregunta es como hacer para que se muestre formateado ese html que esta incrustado, para que la template lo reconozca como html y no como un texto plano  y al final se muestre  **informe 2020**

Comment: Seria conveniente que, especifiques mas tu duda o pongas un ejemplo para poder ayudarte

Comment: Hola Paul! Te recomiendo leer [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que te sea más fácil obtener ayuda, normalmente este tipo de preguntas suelen acabar cerradas.

Comment: Seria así: `{{ campo_textfield|safe }}`. Por otra parte recomiendo usar un ckeditor.

Comment: Gracias Julio, esa opción era la que buscaba, no conocia de ckeditor voy a consultar muchas gracias